# Invalid Scope Parameter in RunningValue in a line chart

Tags: reporting-services

I can't for the life of me figure this out.  I have a table in SSRS that has a data that looks like this:

```
days   P  
0      0.99  
26     0.98  
57     1  
97     0.97  
99     0.99
```

What I want to do is plot a running product of the values in P. I can get them in a table by calculating the following value:

```vb
=exp(RunningValue(Fields!P.Value, Sum, "data"))
```

And that works fine.  When I try to scatter-plot it, however, nothing is showing up in my plots.

For my value I have:

```
X: =Fields!d.Value  
Y: =exp(RunningValue(Fields!P.Value, Sum, "data"))
```

Any Category or Series value I try seems to break the plot, giving me some variation on the following error:

> The DataPoint expression for the chart 'chart1' has a scope parameter that is not valid for RunningValue, RowNumber or Previous. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to the name of a containing group within the matrix 'chart1'.

Comment: What version of Reporting Services is this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it recently but older versions of Reporting Services didn't allow running totals to be used in charts.

However, like most things you can fake it using SQL:

```
SELECT Detail.days, MIN(Detail.P) AS P, SUM(RunTotal.P) AS PRunTotal
FROM MyTable AS Detail 
INNER JOIN MyTable AS RunTotal ON RunTotal.days <= Detail.days
GROUP BY Detail.days
ORDER BY Detail.days
```